# Partial tag helper for razor pages doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I have problem with partial tag helper when I want to render some partial pages in my view. So problem is that one partial tag placed in my view works fine, but another tag placed below doesn't work. Can someone explain what is causing this problem?[image]

Comment: Your screenshot seems to show two slightly different ways of referencing `Model.Item2` -- in the first case your reference does NOT have the AT symbol at the beginning, but in the second case it does have the AT symbol.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @DavidTansey of course there are different ways, it's because if partial tag helper don't work I can't find my model without AT symbol. There is no problems with referencing model. If be honest, I want to use partial tag helper because I can render partial without passing model in this option

Comment: @Örvar there is no error, partial just doesn't renders. I use this partials to get them in modal windows, so when I call modal window it's just don't render contents of my partials. But there is problems only if partial tag doesn't work. Of course I can call partials using @Html.Partial/PartialAsync, but as i said in previous reply, I want to render partial without passing model. And In general I'm curious why there is such problem that one partial works and other doesn't works...

Comment: Then I would suggest you remove the ``model="@Model.Item2"`` part from the ``<partial>`` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid markup in the div that acts as a container for the Comments. There is an extraneous double quote:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 border rounded m-3 card" ">
                                              ^
```

You can see a green squiggle underneath it in the image you posted. Razor expects tags and quotes within them to be balanced. Remove that and you should see the second partial acquire the same syntax highlighting as the first one.